# The speed of JIT compiling method call compared to reflection in .NET

Tags: .net, jit

Reflection is usually said to be slow. However, when .NET JIT compiler needs to compile a call to a method it needs to refer to the same module metadata tables (if I understand it correctly). Does method (and field) lookup incur the same perf. hit in JIT compilation and in reflection?

Answer (score 0):

I think the two might be comparable, but don't forget that JITting is a one-time cost, while using reflection isn't.